# Eclipse not resolving Workspace Artifacts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have an multi module maven project which I need to import in eclipse, i'm facing an issue after importing that project. My project is multi module with inter dependency like below.
**P1 having dependency entry in P2 and P2 having dependency entry in P3 and so on.**

```
P (parent)
 |_
    P1
      |_
        P2  -> <dependency>P1</dependency>
        |_
          P3  -> <dependency>P2</dependency>
            |_
              P4  -> <dependency>P3</dependency>
```

Now when I try to import this in eclipse it is not resolving **P1 for P2 and P2 for P3 and so on**. Though I set *Resolve Workspace Artifacts* checked in (true) maven run build properties and also maven global property. still it is unable to get its dependency from Work space and showing compile time error due to un-resolve reference from previous project artifact.Please suggest me some way to resolve this issue .

[image: Image for project structure :]

[image: Image for set work space resolution]

I have depdency of tc83 in to tc90 tc83 compiled perfectly but not tc90, and also I set work space resolution to true.

Comment: It looks like your project structure is not correct. You need to have one root and all other modules under it.

Comment: I have correct project structure that is P -> is parent and under that, all other module(project) P1, P1, P3, P4.

Comment: Open the "problems" view and see if there is any Maven problems.

Comment: yes there is some problem, like - plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.connecs:maven-antrun-connec:1.3:run (execution: default, phase: compile)
And
Duplicating managed version 2.4 for maven-install-plugin
And
GroupId is duplicate of parent groupId this are three errors are shown in maven problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set the versions correctly? You have to reference the exact version of P1, P2, etc. in your dependencies section (including SNAPSHOT).

Furthermore, the modules have to be part of the workspace as separate eclipse projects. If they are not shown, import them as Maven projects. Furthermore, you should check that the Resolve Workspace Artifacts is set to true for all of the projects.

Comment: Thanks Meier for answer, all dependencies have version as <version>${project.version}</version> with there artifact. And yes my all project are imported into eclipse(imported all project from parent) and also Workspace Artifacts is set to true for all of the projects in that.

Comment: Maybe you could add an image of your eclipse project structure to your question - one of the used pom files would also be helpful.

Comment: JF Meier you may see images.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in m2eclipse when building a war for a web application:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-192

This bug could be the cause of your problem. It's known since several years, according to the link above it's fixed in the maven war plugin version 2.6. I just disovered it, let's try it out.

Comment: tried it with version 2.6 and worked but still failing on maven-ear-plugin